# ASP.NET Web Forms Routing Ambiguity

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes, url-routing

I have routing rules in the following order:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Corporate", "Shop/{Category}", "~/Shop.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("GiftType", "Shop/{Category}", "~/Shop.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Occasion", "Shop/{Category}", "~/Shop.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Discounted", "Shop/{Category}", "~/Shop.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Featured", "Shop/{Featured}", "~/Shop.aspx");
```

Links I'm using:

```
<a href="~/Shop/Corporate" title="Corporate Gifts" runat="server">Corporate</a>
<a href="~/Shop/GiftType" title="Shop by Gift Type" runat="server">Gift Type</a>
<a href="~/Shop/Occasion" title="Shop by Occasion" runat="server">Occasion</a>
<a href="~/Shop/Discounted" title="Discounted" runat="server">Discounted</a>
<a href='<%# "~/Shop/"+Eval("Featured") %>' title='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'
    runat="server">
```

In the code-behind of the destination page, the following code works and I don't know why. The switch statement is executing for a case value of "True" for "Featured"? It's like I'm not differentiating these routes from each other according to the placeholders?

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["Category"] != null)
{
    string category = Page.RouteData.Values["Category"].ToString();

    switch (category)
    {
        case ("Corporate"):
            Response.Write("Corporate");
            break;
        case ("GiftType"):
            Response.Write("GiftType");
            break;
        case ("Occasion"):
            Response.Write("Occasion");
            break;
        case ("Discounted"):
            Response.Write("Discounted");
            break;
        // Do not want the following to be picked up here for Category param
        case ("True"):
            Response.Write("Featured");
            break;           
    }
}
```

What I want to work code-wise is something like this:

```
    if (Page.RouteData.Values["Category"] != null)
    {
        string category = Page.RouteData.Values["Category"].ToString();

        switch (category)
        {
            case ("Corporate"):
                Response.Write("Corporate");
                break;
            case ("GiftType"):
                Response.Write("GiftType");
                break;
            case ("Occasion"):
                Response.Write("Occasion");
                break;
            case ("Discounted"):
                Response.Write("Discounted");
                break;          
        }
    }
    else if (Page.RouteData.Values["Featured"].ToString() == "True")
    {
        Response.Write("Featured");
    }
```

Comment: It should suffice with 1 MapPageRoute call, any of them would do.  When you have gotten your head around that it is probably easier to figure out how to do the rest.  Another tip: Use Glimpse to se how the routing executes. HTH

Comment: Does Glimpse work with Web Forms? Thought it was only for MVC...

Comment: Probably only MVC yes; didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one route for your categories:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("shop-categories", "Shop/{Category}", "~/Shop.aspx");
```

And then you can build the URL like you were, or like

```
<a id="a1" href="<%$ RouteUrl:Category=Discounted,routename=shop-categories%>" title="Discounted" runat="server">Discounted</a>
```

I would think you'd want a different route (for clarity's sake) for featured, like

```
routes.MapPageRoute("featured", "Shop/Featured/{Featured}", "~/Shop.aspx");
```

and the link (both ways):

```
<a id="A2" href="<%$ RouteUrl:Featured=False,routename=featured%>" title="Featured" runat="server">Featured False</a>
<a id="A3" href="~/Shop/Featured/True" title="Featured" runat="server">Featured True</a>
```

Then your code-behind:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["Category"] != null)
{
    //something
}
else if (Page.RouteData.Values["Featured"] != null)
{
    //something
}
```

And the benefit of building the link like I showed would be if you decide to change your routes... you won't break anything. Let's say you eventually don't like the look of the URL `/Shop/Featured/` and just want it to be `/Featured/`, so you change your route:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("featured", "Featured/{Featured}", "~/Shop.aspx");
```

Now in my example above, the link with `id="A2"` will still work, whereas `id="A3"` is now broken.